# Why was Frank necessary?

Tags: plot-explanation, ending, fantastic-beasts, fantastic-beasts-where-to-find-them

**Slight spoilers below**

At the end of *Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them*, Newt releases Frank to distribute the Swooping Evil's venom as a mass Obliviation spell.

He says Frank is their "only hope". Why is that? We know wizards can modify the weather (Ron accidentally makes it snow in one of the movies). Combine that with brooms and it seems Frank was hardly needed for the task.

Comment: i thought about it.. cinematically, it would be a grand thing to do (the majestic bird off to do its work) ! i guess that was the purpose.. and it sort of looked genius !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think Frank was fast and readily available. The longer they had to wait to fix the problem of the No-Maj's remembering, the more likely it would be that someone would remember. The venom had to get to the rain cloud and no one had a broom that I noticed.

Answer (score 10):

I believe the realisation that Frank was their only/best option has a few reasons to support it.

Firstly, Frank’s bond with Newt was clearly very strong- it seems as though this particular beast has a strong emotional intelligence and, as is revealed in the story, was rescued by Newt from Egypt. The very reason that Newt is travelling through America illegally is to get to Arizona, and to free Frank in his own habitat. This entire backstory shows the strength of the bond between them, and the fact that Frank never tried to escape when possible, and warns him of any impending danger, further proves the fact. Frank is dependable and the two can understand each other in a way that possibly other creatures can’t, or at least, the other animals that Newt does have this bond with aren’t capable of doing what Frank can.

Secondly, Frank can control the weather. The information given earlier (and later) in the film is that the Swooping Evil’s venom has powerful obliviatory properties, and Newt has been experimenting with diluting the fluid to the appropriate amount to create an obliviate potion of sorts. Frank and Newt’s bond enabled them to work together, control the weather (thereby diluting the potion) and successfully obliviating the area.

Thirdly, time is of the essence. Much as the force-field surrounding the disaster site, as well as in Harry Potter’s final fights, it can take multiple, powerful wizards to work toward a common goal, and I suspect it takes an adept skill, as well as strong concentration, to maintain the spell and to not ‘drop the ball’ so to speak. Dealing with people in these situations calls for communication, planning, and as per my next point, trust.

We have a plot twist revealed at the end of the film in which an amount of trust for a character has been lost. Trusting official members of MACUSA is understandably a brand new hot-topic and so, placing their trust in an animal who will take instructions is clearly a preferable option at that exact moment.

All of this is aided by the fact that the group are currently in disaster recovery. Many MACUSA members are repairing the city and dealing with other evolving situations which we aren’t exposed to, such as detaining a powerful villain at the end of the event. This also left the large group of no-majes just outside of the event still snapping photographs and writing notes. Do note too that this is in a time before mobile phones, and as such, the reports would be made before they would all be communicated to the press headquarters. Anyone still outside and at the scene will be detached from who they are intended to report to, and so holding them there to obliviate them would be ideal, but not very subtle or time-sensitive. Allowing for a large, golden, 6-winged beast to billow out from the ground and into the sky would undoubtedly hold the population’s attention long enough for the rain to fall and for the obliviatory properties to activate. Which they do.

Frank really was their best option for that moment- no other beast or wizard we had been exposed to in Fantastic Beasts could have performed what Frank did. Even the Swooping Death itself would have taken too much time, delivered too-strong dosages, and likely would have become distracted by eating the no-majes brains.

Comment: that is some great analysis @Gray Roberts  ! but i was wondering how the rain effected the wizards. they're obviously not immune to the rain or eventually would have to drink water. They should obviously remember what happened ! I don't understand how the wizards got around this ..

Comment: Thank you very much!! With that point though, in honesty, I agree. I have to assume there's some handwaving going on as there were families inside the buildings, and even the account manager from the bank is _in his shower_ and I'm not sure how the obliviatory rain affects him. My assumption is that rain is more than just raindrops... there's vapour and moisture in the air, all of which would hold a portion of the diluted Swooping Evil venom. I'm not entirely sure, and couldn't hazard a guess outside of this comment.

Comment: Ohh-- sorry, you said the wizards... I was curious about the no-majes who were outside the physical scope of the rain but were still affected. In terms of the wizards... again, I don't know. They wouldn't have been made aware of that momentary decision to send Frank out, so perhaps some were affected. I imagine the wizarding community would right the wrongs here, and anyone affected would either find out through word of mouth, or perhaps MACUSA would request any affected wizards to attend the offices to have their memory returned. Perhaps a magical warning went out, and they apparated away?

Comment: Oh i actually got the reference to the shower and water.. the rain water does get mixed up with the water that the civilians use.. So when they use tap water (and the source body has some of the rain water - its usually the same with lot of water bodies and home utilization around the world) they get effected by the Swooping Evil Venom. I'm really bothered by the effect it had on the Wizarding community.

Comment: Ahh, see my memory is fading of this. I thought the wizards were repairing the streets (and the water towers on top of the apartment buildings) _before_ the rain fell. If I'm wrong then fair enough, but in my memory, this is unanswered.